# JSONDecodeError in discordpy bot while using virus total API

Tags: python, json, api

I have coded a discord bot to check if a url is safe or not but it only takes two links and then displays this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "api.py", line 75, in on_message
    x = (json.dumps(response.json()).find("true"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

algorithm behind my bot is to check every message for link if found add it to a csv file and if that link is of instagram, youtube or discord it will delete them if not then it will use virus total api to check if it is safe or not if safe then does nothing and if unsafe then delete it also checks that if the link is there in csv file or not if it is there then delete else do nothing

**code for my discord bot is**

```
import requests
import discord
import re
import discord
import json
import csv
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import pytz



api = open("api.txt", "r").read()# I've opted to just save my api to a text file. 
token = open("token.txt", "r").read()  # I've opted to just save my token to a text file. 

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:
        varin = f"{message.content}"
        def search(string):
            regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\.,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
            url = re.findall(regex,string)
            return [x[0] for x in url]
            
        var = str((search(varin)))
        bad_chars = "]","[",",","'"

        for i in bad_chars :
            var = var.replace(i, '')
        
        with open('links.csv', 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') 
            for row in reader:
                for field in row:
                    if field == var:
                        print ("is in file" )
                        await message.delete() 
        if var != "":
            with open('links.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
                writer = csv.writer(write_obj, dialect='excel')
                current = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
                current = current.strftime("%H:%M:%S  ")
                writer.writerow([current ,var])
        var = str(var)
        varDI=var.find('discord.gg')
        varYT=var.find('youtube.com/channel')
        varIN=var.find('instagram.com')
        if varIN != -1:
            await message.delete()
            
        elif varYT != -1:  
            await message.delete()
            
        elif varDI != -1:  
            await message.delete()    
            
        else:
            url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/scan'
            params = {'apikey': api, 'url':var}
            response = requests.post(url, data=params)
        
            time.sleep(1)
        
            url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'
            params = {'apikey': api, 'resource':var}
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            x = (json.dumps(response.json()).find("true")) 
            print(x)
            if x!=-1:
                await message.delete()


       
        

client.run(token)
```

bot.py,link.csv,token.txt,api.txt are in the same directory

Comment: Try logging whatever `response` is here: `response = requests.get(url, params=params)`t could throw that error because the response isn't valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting comes from the JSON decoder during the `response.json()` call. This means the response you are getting is not a valid JSON string, which could have happened for multiple reasons.

Most likely, the response have had a [non-successful status code](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes), and didn't contain any payload. The `/url/report` endpoint expects that the `resource` parameter is either an id of a previously performed scan, or a valid URL, otherwise the API responds with a status code 400. This would be easy to fix by ignoring unsuccessful or empty responses:

```py
url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'
params = {'apikey': api, 'resource':var}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    return

if not response.text:
    return

x = response.text.find("true")
```

### Making sense of error codes

The code above might not be the ideal solution, as unsuccessful response could also mean that your API key has expired or wasn't provided (`response.status_code == 403`), or the request itself was malformed (`response.status_code == 400`). This would effectively allow malicious links through, as every error request will be ignored.

To account for that, I'd suggest to raise an error for all non-2xx status codes. This can be done by calling [`response.raise_for_status()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status). Alternatively, you could return early if `response.status_code == 400`, and raise for the rest of errors.